# android how to set a fake location to phone

Tags: android, location

I trying to use Mock location to the phone but it showing exceptions,

my code is below,

```
Location location = new Location(MOCK_PROVIDER_NAME);
                        location.setLatitude(latitude);
                        location.setLongitude(longitude);
                        location.setTime(new Date().getTime());
                        locationManager.setTestProviderEnabled(MOCK_PROVIDER_NAME, true);
                        locationManager.setTestProviderLocation(MOCK_PROVIDER_NAME, location);
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Latitude: "+location.getLatitude()+" Longitude: "+location.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
```

i gave MOCK_PROVIDER_NAME= "gps" but this one is not taking also i tried with "network" and "spoof" , but its not working.

Where i am going wrong, plz anybody tell me.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here are two possible causes of your issue:

a security exception:

> if the ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION permission is not present or the
>   Settings.Secure.ALLOW_MOCK_LOCATION system setting is not enabled

Or IllegalArgumentException:

> if a provider with the given name already exists

I got those quotes from: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#addTestProvider

If it's not one of those to Exceptions that you are getting, then give us the stack trace of your error as well as whatever line the stack trace shows in your code is the issue.

I'm GUESSING you didn't declare the permission in manifest AND/OR "Allow Mock Locations" is off in the development settings.

Comment: i given the permission and also i enable the MOCK_LOCATION in the phone, it showing exception for parameters "gps", "network"

Comment: You get an IllegalArgumentException if a provider with the given name already exists. What exception are you getting if that doesn't resolve it?